# Showing CustomValidator in modal dialog

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have my ValidationSummary showing in a modal dialog.  That is working fine.

However my code-behind performs some database lookups and adds messages with a CustomValidator to my ValidationSummary.

This worked fine before I started showing my ValidationSummary in the dialog.  But now when the CustomValidator is invalid it doesn't show in the ValidationSummary dialog.

The dialog comes up when other fields are invalid, but not for the CustomValidator messages from code-behind.

Here's the code that shows the dialog when the page isn't valid:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function WebForm_OnSubmit() {
        if (typeof (ValidatorOnSubmit) == "function" && ValidatorOnSubmit() == false) {
            $("#modal_validationSummary").modal('show');
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

Validation Summary code:

```
<div class="modal modal-danger" id="modal_validationSummary" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">                
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Invalid Login</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body clearfix">

                <asp:ValidationSummary ID="LoginValidationSummary" runat="server" 
                ValidationGroup="LoginGroup" HeaderText="<div class='validationheader'>Please address the issues below</div>" 
                CssClass="validationsummary" DisplayMode="BulletList"/>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">                    
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-clean" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My code-behind that adds the CustomValidator:

```
CustomValidator cv = new CustomValidator();
cv.IsValid = false;
cv.ErrorMessage = "Login not found. Please try again.";
cv.ValidationGroup = "LoginGroup";
this.Page.Validators.Add(cv);
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the sequence of events is:  you post back, the validator is added, the page renders, and the Validation Summary doesn't show the error?

At what point is the validation summary displayed?  If it's before your initial postback, then your validation message can't appear because validation is preventing you from posting back, and the validation doesn't happen until after postback.

There might also be an issue with the `CustomValidator` not being added to the `Controls` collection, but I'm not sure about that.

ETA:  a little research reinforced my belief that the pop-up `ValidationSummary` window only works with *client-side* validation.  Yours is server-side.  You can make a `CustomValidator` function as a client-side validator while still performing work on the server, but you need to:

1. Define a client-side validation function;
2. Perform an AJAX call within that client-side function;
3. Declare your `CustomValidator` in the markup.  (You could still add it dynamically, but it would be on your initial render, and you'd have to add it to the `Controls` collection.)

That's the very condensed version of it, anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.  I'm new at this so that information was very helpful.